# MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Mongo 5.0.1 and Node 17.2.0
this is my code
If I connect want to connect with Atlas with this code it runs successfully but when I try to connect with the local Database it gives this error.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

async function main(){
    const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    try{
        await client.connect();
        await listDatabases(client);
    } catch (e){
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}
main().catch(console.error);

async function listDatabases(client) {
    databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();

    console.log("Databases:");
    databasesList.databases.forEach(db => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
};
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\web development\nodeDemo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:330:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the local MongoDB is started..?

Comment: Yes the mongodb is started

Answer (score 14):

use this as your uri

```
  const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by enabling the IPv6 in the `mongodb.config`

more info here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.ipv6

Comment: Confirmed with Node 18.5. None of the other solutions (i.e. localhost, 127.0.0.1) changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL:

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

Instead of:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I simply replaced the connection string from **'mongodb://localhost/MyDBName'** with **'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/MyDBName'**. Also, please ensure that the MongoDB server is up and running.

[image]